# Query Optimisation to reduce the time period of query

Tags: performance, query-optimization

I have a query below:

```
declare @max int

select @max = max(len(RPVINVNoSpace)) from jde_SupplierInvoices
update jde_SupplierInvoices set RPVINVNumeric = ''

declare @loop int = 1
while @loop <= @max

begin 

update jde_SupplierInvoices set RPVINVNumeric = RPVINVNumeric + 
    case when substring(RPVINVNoSpace,@loop,1) in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
            then substring(RPVINVNoSpace,@loop,1)
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'jan' then '01'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'feb' then '02'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'mar' then '03'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'apr' then '04'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'may' then '05'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'jun' then '06'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'jul' then '07'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'aug' then '08'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'sep' then '09'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'oct' then '10'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'nov' then '11'
            when substring(lower(RPVINVNoSpace),@loop,3) = 'dec' then '12'
            else ''
    end
set @loop = @loop + 1
end
```

The challenge is to come up with a better way to re-implement this and no CLR allowed.Basically this query is updating the column value(RPVINVNumeric) to numeric derived from another column(RPVINVNoSpace) which consist of alphanumeric characters.
The table has millions of rows and the script takes nearly 4 mins to run.
Here is the sample data for reference:

[data sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Wl6.jpg)

I am not able to format the data screenshot further apologies for that.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Arti

Comment: Add a tag for the specific database engine.

Comment: Add plain text examples of RPVINVNoSpace values and investigate `DISTINCT len(RPVINVNoSpace)` values, perhaps adding WHERE clauses could reduce the number of rows involved in each case. 
Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: The database is SQL Server 2012.